# Can't override Bootstrap .help-block margin-top in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a Rails app, and I'm trying to override two styles of the .help-block class from Bootstrap in my custom.css.scss. Here's the css:

```
.help-block {
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container outer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6 offset3">
            <div class="form-container">
            ...
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                ...
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="nickname">Nichname*</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="nickname" required>
                            <span class="help-block">Example: "Mrs. Locke," "Mr. Almeida"</span>
                            ...
```

The font-size works with no issues. However, no matter what I do, the margin-top doesn't override. Apparently, I don't have enough reputation yet to post images, so I can't post what chrome developer tools shows, but here's a [link](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/058167ed-988f-4c2a-b024-194eb93d2f98/7df5472b0b6c5214a939b48890adc1c2/res/f5d3fe67-f4a7-4d51-ba01-b954fe6129c0/skitch.png) to the screenshot.

My override (at line 4922) is definitively (as far as I can tell) the last reference to .help-block in the entire final css file, and yet the one from line 1528 is the one which survives. I've also tried (as an experiment) overriding all the margins:

```
.help-block {
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

When I do this, all margins get overridden except the top margin (again). What am I missing here?

Comment: try: [class^="control"] .help-block {/* your css */} to override bootstraps value, if it works , you should use an heavier selector :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will sound stupid but... have you tried using `!important`?

```
.help-block {
    margin-top: 5px !important;
    margin-left: 5px; #or whatever
    margin-right: 5px; #or whatever
    margin-bottom: 5px; #or whatever
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: May not be the best result but it has solved everything for me so far.

Comment: I know. For the best: see my answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926522/flat-ui-round-corners-css-html/20926652#20926652) talking about the order of css to overwrite FlatUI or Bootstrap.

Comment: Remember to take into consideration the load order to overwrite css's classes

Comment: Thanks @skozz. Not stupid at all. That was it. So my problem is solved. But I'm still flummoxed why I would need to use !important when simply overriding it later in my css sheet (the only one) should be enough. *sigh*